# Simple child theme modification but links are broken

Tags: theme-development, themes, child-theme

I have created a simple child theme to modify the [Minimal theme by Elegant Themes](http://www.elegantthemes.com/gallery/minimal/).

The child theme loads with the changes I have made, but the links to pages in the header are all messed up.  Rather than the page links I have selected appearing in the header, links to all categories appear in addition to links to these pages.

Even if the only modification I make is as follows:

```
@import url("../Minimal/style.css");

a {
    text-decoration: underline !important;
}
```

The links at the top are still messed up and the category links are improperly displayed in addition to the page links, even though I am not making any other changes. (But the underline does display.)

What is causing this issue?

EDIT: Clarified that category links are what is being display incorrectly.

Comment: Messed up = ? Is this a css or a WP Q? Doesn't elegant themes offer support?

Comment: Messed up in the sense that displayed links should not be changing just based on making a simple css change.

Comment: Elegant themes does offer support but I thought this was more of an issue with how child themes work in wordpress and I'd like to try to isolate the issue before I go to them.

Comment: I would say that this is a question for ElegantThemes support. Without looking at the Theme's code, I would guess that the problem is lack of inherent Child-Theme support in the Minimal Theme codebase - e.g. using `get_stylesheet_directory()` instead of `get_template_directory()`, and the like.

Comment: Thanks for the info--I am going to contact them and I will post here when I get an answer in case someone else has the same problem.

Comment: I'd take a look at what @Chip Bennet suggested.

Comment: Yes--I was responding to him in my previous comment.  I can obviously edit the original theme codebase, but that would defeat what I am trying to do--which is to maintain a system where updates to the theme don't overwrite any of my changes.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem may be similar to this question: [How could child theme be different than parent theme if I haven't made changes?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32217/how-could-child-theme-be-different-than-parent-theme-if-i-havent-made-changes)

When you activate a child theme (assuming it's properly setup), you will inherit all of the parent theme's styles (and usually widgets), but you will not inherit:

- Menu assignment to theme locations
- Theme options (sometimes, but I seem to recall Elegant Themes is an instance that doesn't inherit options).

Hence, you're probably seeing the expected behavior, and it's not a problem with the child theme or WordPress, but rather a change in settings stemming from a new theme being activated.